# Find if it is possible to draw a closed (cycle; not a path) continuous line...

Tags: graph-theory

... that crosses exactly once (only once) each interior line segment of the rectangle, whilst staying inside the rectangle for these 2 rectangles.

My immediate reasoning was to remove all the outside edges, but keep the vertices. As a result, I said no to both (as there was no Euler cycle in the graphs that remained after doing so). Is this a matter of simply removing edges & checking for an Euler cycle as I initially thought? Or should I remove any line segment connecting to the outside perimeter as well?

[image: 2 graphs]

Comment: I don't really understand what you did, but the main idea solving this problem is to construct a graph which vertices correspond to the regions inside the rectangle, and edges are connected if the two regions have a common boundary.

Comment: I removed the four edges of the perimeter for each rectangle. For the remaining graph(s); I tested if an Euler cycled existed within each of them.

Comment: I am not really sure to have understood the question, but if I did ... if you have two neighbours vertices with an odd number of edges it is impossible what you are asking. This is because if the path passes through a vertex walking on two of its edges the only way to pass also on the third one would be if that edge is the last one of the entire path. Moreover since you are looking for a cycle the same reasoning can be done with just one vertex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a path passes through a vertex, it walks on two of its edges and the only way to pass also on the third one would be if that edge is the last one of the entire path. But since you are looking for a loop, this is impossible. Also relaxing the requirement from "loop" to "path", it is also impossible since there are two odd neighbours vertices.

Comment: Yes, I concluded the same. I didn't seem to understand it at first either because it was written somewhat poorly (not on my behalf). The question was given as is.